# ¿Cómo realizar un VScrolbar en un widget del tipo Box con Gtk?

Tags: scroll, interfaz-gráfica, gtk, vala

Estoy realizando un proyecto en `Vala` y `Gtk+` el cual necesito que me permita poder agregar un scrollbar que contenga un box o si no se puede con un Layout o Fixed, precisamente un scrollbar vertical. Tengo problemas para agregarlo a mi proyecto porque no encuentro en ningún lugar la forma de realizarlo, solamente aparecen ejemplos usando `ScrolledWindow` que justamente no es lo que busco sino uno que pueda usarlo en un Widget en vez de la ventana, como ya mencione anteriormente.
Les muestro una parte del codigo programado en Vala:

```
Box caja = new Box(Orientation.VERTICAL, 0);//Widget que quiero que se pueda controlar con un scroll
Label label = new Label("Esto es una etiqueta");
caja.pack_start(label, false, false, 0);
...      //Agrego dentro de "caja" mas elementos, para que se llene.
caja.show_all();
```

Acá un ejemplo utilizando `ScrolledWindow`:

```
Gtk.ScrolledWindow scrolled = new Gtk.ScrolledWindow (null, null);
this.add (scrolled);
scrolled.add(caja);
```

Pero no realiza nada, ni siquiera muestra el Scroll.
Alguna forma para solucionar esto, me harían un gran favor.

Comment: por que no utilizas un viewport, puedes agregar un scroll

Comment: Me olvidé que esta pregunta ya la había resuelto por mi cuenta. 
Esa opción era valida, pero además tenia que agregar un elemento Alignament para que el Scrollbar se colocara en ese objeto y no en la ventana entera y de esa manera podía colocar el Scroll en cualquier lugar.
Gracias igual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

utiliza un `Gtk.Viewport` dentro de un `Gtk.ScrolledWindow` y luego agrega tu contenedor `Gtk.Box` para poder usar el scroll dentro del Widget (un ejemplo):

```
public class Application : Gtk.Window {
    public Application () {
        // Window:
        this.title = "Viewport";
        this.window_position = Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER;
        this.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);
        this.set_default_size (400, 400);

        // ScrolledWindow:
        var scrolled = new Gtk.ScrolledWindow (null, null);
        this.add (scrolled);

        //Viewport:
        var viewport = new Gtk.Viewport (null, null);
        viewport.set_size_request (30, 30);
        scrolled.add (viewport);

        //Box
        var caja = new Gtk.Box(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 700);
        var label = new Gtk.Label("Esto es una etiqueta");
        caja.pack_start(label, false, false, 0);
        caja.show_all();

        viewport.add (caja);

    }

    public static int main (string[] args) {
        Gtk.init (ref args);
        Application app = new Application ();
        app.show_all ();
        Gtk.main ();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Puedes guiarte de la documentación del valadoc sobre `Gtk.Viewport`.

> **Valadoc**: [Gtk.Viewport - gtk+-3.0](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Viewport.html)